# Problem with themes on Debian 10 Buster XFCE

Tags: debian, xfce, theme

I have a small problem with installing themes completely on Debian 10 Buster.

After select the theme I wish in the "Appearance" menu, taskbar's colors and some elements change but the minimize and close buttons always stay the same.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHbau.png

The buttons look the same no matter what theme I choose and it's really stressing because they look really bland.

I must mention that I am a relative new Linux user that is here to learn, so please don't be harsh on me. :D

Answer (score 2):

The minimize and close buttons are apart of your Window Manager theme.

You can change them with the XFCE Application Menu > Settings > Window manager menu.

Comment: oh man, that was so simple.... yet i overlooked WIndow manager menu when i opened Settings tab...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnBaltariu Don't stress it. Just keep looking up things you don't know and eventually you learn this stuff. Xfce is my favorite because everything is so customizable.